# Why is Marx more prominent than Engels?

Tags: communism

Both Karl Marx and Friedrich Engels coauthored the Communist Manifesto. However, the philosophies described in the book are commonly referred to as *Marxism*. Also, Marx is a much more common name found in history textbooks focussed on the communist movement in the 1800s and the formation of the USSR.

For what reason is Marx so much more predominant than Engels in history?

Comment: Welcome to the site; as [ask] points out, we prefer that you do preliminary research before asking a question and document that in your question.  Your search question reveals 681,000 results in google, and there are good answers in the first five results.    I hope you'll consult those, revise your question to something a bit tougher, and continue with the site.

Comment: ".. . while in his extensive correspondence with German socialists Engels modestly presented his own secondary place in the couple's intellectual relationship. . . " [wikipedia on Engels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Engels#Ideological_legacy)

Comment: Marx did a lot more things than just the *Manifesto*. Most famously, *The capital* and *The 18 Brumaire of Napoleon Bonaparte*, that insist in the historical materialism POV. Engels did some other works in his own, but none of them became as famous.

Comment: Because his name is shorter, and has an "X" in it, which is cool.

Comment: Also, calling it "Engelismus" ("Angelism") would sound silly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The main work which lays the foundation of Marxism is not the Communist Manifesto.
It is the many-volume theoretic work which is called Capital (Das Kapital) by Marx alone. The Manifesto is just a short pamphlet, stating the main conclusions.
In the Capital, Marx developed an economic theory, from which he concluded the inevitability of the development of society towards communism.

Many later socialists recognize the analysis given in Capital, though not all subscribe to the statements in the Communist manifesto.

Engels never positioned himself as a leader of the Communist movement. He just supported Marx (especially financially) and wrote several books promoting Marx's views..

Comment: Although didn't Engels complete 'Das Kapital' after Marx's death, although it was published in Marx's name?

Answer (score 0):

It is worth adding that the official Soviet propaganda treated Marx, Engels and Lenin as equals all up to the end of the USSR, as manifested, e.g., by the canonical images featuring all three of them, which were hanged all over the country in the run ups to the Revolution day or May 1st ([image source](https://communiste-shop.fr/products/drapeau-marx-engels-lenin)):
[image]

On the other hand, the official ideology was referred to as [*Marxism-Leninism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marxism%E2%80%93Leninism), stressing that most theoretical developments owed to these two.

Answer (score -4):

Marx's *Das Kapital* is a bourgeois theoretical work aimed at working class readers, but functionally aimed at bourgeois readers with left liberal sympathies hostile to the right liberal trajectory of ostensibly socialist parties in the 1800s: Marx, *Critique of the Gotha Programme.*

In contrast Engels spent his time on historically specific analyses such as *Condition of the Working Class in England 1848,* *Peasants War in Germany,* or *Family Private Property and the State*.

It is a truism that Engels as a bourgeois party boi wrote better works about actual existing working class life, and his work about theory (Anti-Duhring) you would use dog shit to wipe off your shoe.

Marx, the apposite.

Comment: Difficult to parse, and reads more like 'in my opinion now recension' than an analytical answer to the question. No refs. AFAIU: 1st para seems to suffer from 'myth of coherence'? Anti-Gotha is described OK (i guess) but pitched agains Capital: is to me non sequitur here (explanation or refs might help, & as said, I might misunderstand the structure here). 4th para is enigmatic, typo 'opposite'? // I am quite confident you can expand this quite significantly.

Comment: I also find the answer very confusing: It seems to suggest that Marx is more famous than Engels because of his appeal to "bourgeois readers with left liberal sympathies..." while Engels was regarded (by the same circles?) as a "bourgeois party boi(?)" (and, hence, not taken seriously?). If this is what you meant to say, I find it very intriguing and would be interested to see supporting evidence.

Comment: @LangLangC: "No references"? The poster mentions *Das Kapital*, *Critique of the Gotha Programme* and *The Condition of the Working Class ...*.

Comment: Das Kapital is certainly NOT aimed at "working class readers".

Comment: _Das Kapital_ is commonly interpreted as aimed at working class readers, the same readers who staffed Mechanics Institutes.  It is a *truisim* regarding Kapital's literary history.